# Trying to create a repository that I can add to Bitbucket from a Git packfile

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket

I was given two files - .pack and .idx.

I created a folder and ran `git init` to initialize the folder as a repository.

I have used `git unpack-objects`.

I believe the file was 'unpacked.' I now have 15,000+ files inside .git/objects.

Let's say I have C:\repos\glen (where I ran `git init`)

Inside C:\repos\glen I have a .git folder (result of running `git init` above)

Inside C:\repos\glen.git\objects I have the 15,000+ files (result of running `git unpack-objects`)

Where I am stuck (I know it's probably very simple) is.. what's next?

I have the 15,000+ loose files inside the .git\objects folder.

**How do I get a source tree? How do I get all of this into a Bitbucket repository?**

Thank you so much!

Glen

Comment: From `C:\repos\glen`, what do you get for `git config --local --get core.bare`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to have a working directory to push. To get this repo onto Bitbucket,

1. Go to Bitbucket and set up an empty repo. (Do not add a README or whatever they suggest - leave the repo empty!) Grab the HTTPS or SSH URL they provide; you'll need it in the next step.
2. From `c:\repos\glen`, `git remote add origin $BITBUCKET_URL` (using the URL created in the first step)
3. From `c:\repos\glen`, `git push --all` should push all branches to the `origin` remote that you set up in the second step.

If you'd like a working directory without re-cloning, then you should be able to do `git checkout` (from `c:\repos\glen`) to populate the working directory with the contents of the unpacked objects.